# write dicom header to csv

Tags: python, csv, pydicom

I've got a bunch of .dcm-files (dice-files) where I would like to extract the header and save the information there in a CSV file.

As you can see in the following picture, I've got a problem with the delimiters:

[image: part of dicom-header]

For example when looking at the second line in the picture: I'd like to split it like this:

```
0002 | 0000 | File Meta Information Group Length | UL | 174
```

But as you can see, I've not only multiple delimiters but also sometimes ' ' is one and sometimes not. Also the length of the 3rd column varies, so sometimes there is only a shorter text there, e.g. Image Type further down in the picture.

Does anyone have a clever idea, how to write it in a CSV file?
I use pydicom to read and display the files in my IDE.
I'd be very thankful for any advice :)

Comment: Please do not post images of text, and especially links to images of text.  Links rot, and text should be searchable and cut-n-paste-able.

Comment: Could you add a link to an example file (you could use something like pastebin.com)

Comment: Sorry for this comment, but it has to be stated that I generally think that the idea to convert DICOM into CSV is not very smart. The reason is that CSV "is a table" while DICOM "is a tree". For that reason, CSV is generally inappropriate for converting DICOM files. You output looks very conversion unfriendly in general. You may want to give dcmdump from the DCMTK a try which produces a more uniform output.

Comment: Mark: I'll remember it next time, thanks for the remark.

Martin: I've uploaded an example file here: https://easyupload.io/sm6idj but darcymason has probably solved my problem :)
@kritzel_sw please don't be sorry. I appreciate your comment! I'm quite new to dcm-files. But further down the road I plan on implementing the files in a neo4j database which is why I need the csv, although it kinda hurts the tree structure. I'll have a look at dcmdump, thank u very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest going back to the data elements themselves and working from there, rather than from a string output (which is really meant for exploring in interactive sessions)

The following code should work for a dataset with no Sequences, would need some modification to work with sequences:

```
import csv
import pydicom
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_file

filename = get_testdata_file("CT_small.dcm")  # substute your own filename here
ds =  pydicom.dcmread(filename)

with open('my.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow("Group Elem Description VR value".split())
    for elem in ds:
        writer.writerow([
            f"{elem.tag.group:04X}", f"{elem.tag.element:04X}",
            elem.description(), elem.VR, str(elem.value)
        ])
```

It may also require a bit of change to make the `elem.value` part look how you want it, or you may want to set the CSV writer to use quotes around items, etc.

Output looks like:

```
Group,Elem,Description,VR,value
0008,0005,Specific Character Set,CS,ISO_IR 100
0008,0008,Image Type,CS,"['ORIGINAL', 'PRIMARY', 'AXIAL']"
0008,0012,Instance Creation Date,DA,20040119
0008,0013,Instance Creation Time,TM,072731
...
```